# How do I run a .py script directly from cmd?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Suppose I have a script called 'run.py', how can I do this?

```
C:\Users\Administrator>run
```

And this script will be executed. Please notice that I don't want a '.py' shown after 'run'.
I am using python 3.3.5, and I tried putting 'C:/python33' into environment variable path. But it didn't work.
It seems like it only works when it's a '.exe' file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add `.py` to your `PATHEXT` environment variable.

From the Python on Windows FAQ, [How do I make Python scripts executable?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable)

> On Windows, the standard Python installer already associates the .py
>   extension with a file type (Python.File) and gives that file type an
>   open command that runs the interpreter (`D:\Program
>   Files\Python\python.exe "%1" %*`). This is enough to make scripts
>   executable from the command prompt as ‘foo.py’. If you’d rather be
>   able to execute the script by simple typing ‘foo’ with no extension
>   you need to add .py to the PATHEXT environment variable.

The exact method for setting environment variables varies with different versions of Windows, but [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) can probably help you out.

Comment: Running like this uses [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so file handles aren't inherited from the parent shell. So to pipe data in or out or redirect to a file, you still need to run Python directly, e.g. `some_command | python run.py > out.txt`. In this case the shell calls [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly with `bInheritHandles` as `TRUE`.